# Map function only returns an image from Array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a simple application. I have an upload which reads multiple images into a hook.
From this I would then like to reduce and display each individual image.
However, React only ever shows me one image

```
useEffect(() => {
const CallMe = async () => {
  // files contains 2 images
  if (files.length > 0) {
    return Promise.all(
      files.map(async (file, idx) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            const image = await resizeFile(file[idx]);
            console.log(image);

            resolve(image);
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
      })
    );
  }
};

CallMe().then((res) => {
  setThumbnails([...thumbnails, res]);
});
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [files]);



 {thumbnails.length &&
    thumbnails?.map((img, idx) => {
      if (img)
        return (
          //ONLY ONCE IS SHOWN
          <img
            key={idx}
            src={img}
            alt="soso"
            height={100}
            width={100}
          ></img>
        );
    })}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is here:

```
setThumbnails([...thumbnails, res]);
```

Two issues there:

1. That uses the initial value of `thumbnails` (I'm guessing `[]`), not the current one when the async work is complete.
2. `res` is an *array*, not an individual image.

   Instead, use the callback form so you're working with up-to-date information, and spread out `res`:

   ```
   setThumbnails((previousThumbnails) => [...previousThumbnails, ...res]);
   ```

   That will also fix the ESLint error you've suppressed. (That error is helpful, I suggest not ignoring it.)

Here are some other issues that you might want to look at:

3. Your `map` look suspect. You have

   ```
   files.map(async (file, idx) => {
   ```

   ...but then you're doing

   ```
   const image = await resizeFile(file[idx]);
   ```

   ...but `file` is already one element from `files`, so unless `files` is an array *of arrays*, you just need `file` not `file[idx]` there. (Even if it is an array of arrays, it seems odd to use the value at index `0` of the first one, then the value at index `1` of the second one, etc.)
4. You're using `new Promise` within an `async` function. That's the [explicit promise creation anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), there's no reason to do that here.
5. Your current code ignores errors resizing the file other than dumping them out to the console. I've assumed you really want to do that, but once you're using `async`/`await`, I'd use `try`/`catch` to handle that.

So taking that all together:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const CallMe = async () => {
        return Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
            try {
                return await resizeFile(file);
            } catch (error) {
                // Not really ideal to just ignore errors
                // Note this will leave an `undefined` in the returned array
                console.log(error);
            }
        }));
    };

    CallMe()
        .then((res) => {
            // Remove blank elements from the array
            res = res.filter(Boolean);
            // If we have any left, use them
            if (res.length) {
                setThumbnails((thumbnails) => [...thumbnails, ...res]);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // ...handle/report error...
        });
}, [files]);
```

---

A couple of notes on this:

```
<img
   key={idx}
   src={img}
   alt="soso"
   height={100}
   width={100}
></img>
```

Since we know your array will change (if `files` changes, which it can if it's from props), using the index as the key will not work correctly; see this from [the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.

They don't say it strongly enough there in my view: you **will** get duplicated display elements or elements that don't get removed from the display, etc. Indexes as keys is only a valid choice for **static** lists.

Finally, `<img ...></img>` is more idiomatically written `<img .../>` in JSX. (And you would never write it in HTML at all; `img` is a void element.)